# Use setXXX or getXXXBuilder to set a nested field in protobuf?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Say we have the following proto messages

```
message Inner {
    string text = 1;
}

message Outer {
    Inner one = 1;
    repeated Inner many = 2;
}
```

Now we need to create a new instance of `Outer`, and there're several ways to do that:

```
String oneString;
List<String> manyStrings;

public Inner getOne() {
    if (oneString == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return Inner.newBuilder().setText(oneString).build();
}

public void fillOne(Supplier<Inner.Builder> builderSupplier) {
    if (oneString != null) {
        builderSupplier.get().setText(oneString);
    }
}

public List<Inner> getMany() {
    if (manyStrings.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return manyStrings.stream().map(s -> Inner.newBuilder().setText(s).build())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public void fillMany(Supplier<Inner.Builder> builderSupplier) {
    for (String s : manyStrings) {
        builderSupplier.get().setText(s);
    }
}


@Test
public void test() {
    // #1
    Outer.Builder builder1 = Outer.newBuilder();
    fillOne(builder1::getOneBuilder);
    fillMany(builder1::addManyBuilder);
    Outer outer1 = builder1.build();
    // #2
    Outer outer2 = Outer.newBuilder()
            .setOne(getOne())
            .addAllMany(getMany())
            .build();

}
```

Which is better, or anything I'm missing?

Comment: It really depends on your code standard or personal habit. From performance aspect, there is no difference I think. I like the second way better

Comment: Thanks, @PatrickChen I like the second way too as Its chain-style API make coding fluently. However, I'm not sure,  I read something about the first way has some benifit on performance cause it can reduce some `build` invocations.

Comment: You could try `javap` to see how JVM handles the code, if there is a difference between the two versions. Sometimes JVM will refactor and optimize the code, maybe they end up the same result.